# Show that for all functions f, g .... the following equivalence holds

Tags: functional-analysis

Would you please help me to solve this exercise?

Show that for all functions $f,g:\,\mathbb{N\,\rightarrow\mathbb{R_{>0}}}$ the following equivalence holds

$$f(n)\in o(g(n))\Longleftrightarrow\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=0$$

Thx!

Comment: Compare the definitions of $o(g(n))$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: By definition $f(n)$ is $o\big(g(n)\big)$ if and only if for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $m_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that $|f(n)|\le\epsilon|g(n)|$ for all $n\ge m_\epsilon$. Since you’re dealing with strictly positive functions, we can ignore the absolute values:

> $f(n)$ is $o\big(g(n)\big)$ iff for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $m_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that $f(n)\le\epsilon g(n)$ for all $n\ge m_\epsilon$.

By definition

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=0$$ iff for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $m_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that $$\left|\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}-0\right|<\epsilon$$ for all $n\ge m_\epsilon$, and once again we can ignore the absolute value:

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=0$$ iff for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $m_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that $$\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}<\epsilon\tag{1}$$ for all $n\ge m_\epsilon$.

Now $(1)$ is obviously equivalent to the statement that $f(n)<\epsilon g(n)$. Thus, your equivalence can be restated as follows:

> $$\begin{array}{c}\text{For each }\epsilon>0\text{ there is an }m_\epsilon\in\Bbb N\text{ such that }f(n)<\epsilon g(n)\text{ for all }n\ge m_\epsilon\\\text{iff}\\\text{For each }\epsilon>0\text{ there is an }m_\epsilon\in\Bbb N\text{ such that }f(n)\le\epsilon g(n)\text{ for all }n\ge m_\epsilon\end{array}\;.$$

See if you can prove that. One direction is trivial, and the other is not hard.